# How do you move between lines in a cell with multiple lines of text in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I have a cell that is multiple lines of text, I can drag the top bar down to see all the different lines in the cell, but when I hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, the cursor goes out of the cell and onto the next.

How do I move up and down the text within a multi-line set of text within one Excel cell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just press <kbd>F2</kbd> on the cell. That will put you in edit mode in which it is possible to use the arrow keys. If you want to enter newlines in the cell yourself, you have to do that with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to edit within the cell
- Keep the <kbd>alt</kbd> key pressed and move around with the <kbd>cursor</kbd> keys
- <kbd>F2</kbd> or `Mouse Click` to enter edit mode
- If you get troubled by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> moving you to the next cell below,
  From the Menu, `Tools` ==> `Options` ==> Edit,
  uncheck "`Move selection after enter`".